# ImageMagick option commands not found

Tags: imagemagick

I'm using ImageMagick to turn my pdf pages into images. It works just fine with default settings but if I try some options, it keeps telling me `command not found`

For now, I'm doing all this from a SSH client.

---

**The command I'm attempting is:**

```
-quality 90 /usr/bin/convert public_html/so/November-2015.pdf[0] output.jpg
```

---

It works just fine without the quality part. I also tried density with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I found out my issue, although I saw this format on other answers the way it works for me is if I put `quality -90` after bringing up convert which makes alot of sense now that I think about it.

```
/usr/bin/convert -quality 90 public_html/so/November-2015.pdf[0] output.jpg
```

Comment: You're on the right track but the best place for -quality 90 is after you have read the input file (that is, put "-quality 90" just before "output.jpg" on the commandline).

Comment: I agree with Glenn Randers-Pehrson about the placement of the quality as it is setting your save quality. As I said in one of your other posts it can be useful to set a -density for the pdf file as well. So you command would be: /usr/bin/convert -density 300 public_html/so/November-2015.pdf[0]  -quality 90 output.jpg